# deny when access to config database

Tags: linux, mongodb

i create a user with role of userAdminAnyDatabase ,but i can not access to config database using this account

```
mongos> use admin;
switched to db admin
mongos> show users;
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51a075cf35978c6326c6350f"),
        "user" : "clustersa",
        "pwd" : "e76cbe5c62d704fa4074a7047fa165f5",
        "roles" : [
                "userAdminAnyDatabase"
        ]
}
mongos> db.auth('clustersa','clustersa')
1
mongos> use config
switched to db config
mongos> db.runCommand( { listshards : 1 } );
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "access denied - use admin db" }
```

Answer (score 2):

userAdminAnyDatabase does not grant read permission to the config database - just the ability to alter any users permissions, including it's own permissions.

If you goal is to create a super user, with power to do everything, add in the clusterAdmin and readWriteAnyDatabase rolls for that user.

Combined privilages are discussed [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#combined-access)